# Protractor - Select brings all options selected, script can't correctly pick one of them

Tags: protractor, automated-tests

The following element is a a select with multiple options:

```
<select _ngcontent-c20="" class="custom-select ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" id="unassignedCustomersSE" multiple="" size="5" xpath="1" style="">
  <!---->
  <option _ngcontent-c20="" value="0: Object" class="ng-star-inserted">PGSTEST1 - Regular Customer </option>
  <option _ngcontent-c20="" value="1: Object" class="ng-star-inserted">PGSTEST3 - Multi Client Customer </option>
  <option _ngcontent-c20="" value="2: Object" class="ng-star-inserted">PGSTEST2 - Pegasus MLP </option>
</select>
```

When I access the page where this element is displayed, I see this:
[image]

All the options comes by default, selected.

If I perform the selecting action by hand (clicking in one of the options) the rest is deselected and the one I clicked gets blue.

[image]

Problem is that when the script tries to do it, I get a different result:
[image]

I just need to select this in order to continue the script but it does not work.

I have already tried few things but it never works properly, could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
elements_access_restrictions.unassigned_customers_select.element(by.cssContainingText('option', data.clients.client_multi_PGSTEST3)).click();
//This click is the button I use to transfer from one select to another
elements_access_restrictions.move_to_assigned_button.click();
```

The way those 2 lines behaves is like I was (when doing it manually) pressing ctrl + click, but as you see, I am not doing that.

Any wonderful magical way to do that work? I already tried also to map all the tags 'option' and work with this but the results are quite the same.

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT/UPDATE**
So... via .click(); it does not work, but!
with this:

```
     browser.actions()
    .mouseMove(elements_access_restrictions.unassigned_customers_select.element(by.cssContainingText('option', data.clients.client_multi_PGSTEST3)))
    .click()
    .perform();
```

Works properly, any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no better idea came, I am using the move action for now. works properly

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already moved on. In case if it helps you or others...

Option 1 :

- Deselect all options
- Select the required option

`var allOptions = element(by.css('select')).all(by.css('option'));
allOptions.each((option) => { option.click()});
allOptions.get(1).click();`

Options 2 :
 - Deselect that are not required

`var allOptions = element(by.css('select')).all(by.css('option'));
allOptions.each((option, index) => { if (index !== 1) { option.click()}});`

API reference : https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder

**Disclaimer** : I am not a fan of `browser.actions()` in general and woudl avoid it anyway i can. There are better and reliable APIs available

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for the ideas, I have tried them already but did not work, I am moving on with the click().perform(), so far it is working fine.